# Is it possible to access the adwords API directly through javascript?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I would like to access the adwords API through a simple single page web application using javascript. I would like to dynamically stop and start some of my adwords campaigns.

I can't seem to find any documentation on the REST endpoints for the API - only documentation for the various libraries.

Is it possible to do this through javascript only?

Answer (score 0):

The current Adwords API is a SOAP-based interface, so there are no REST endpoints to use. It's of course still possible to construct SOAP messages and call operations without using one of the provided libraries.

Having said that, the next evolution of the API (the "[Google Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start)") will support both gRPC and JSON REST-based communication, which would probably fit your scenario better. It's not yet ready for production use, however.